How to universally automate standard rebase + squash before merging a PR, regardless of base branch
The standard requirements for merging at a project I am working on are:

Single commit
Rebased to recent pr_target_branch commit
Has a message with ticket number and description

There are multiple branches I work on, the reqiurements are the same and the process is almost, but not quite, automatic. What I do:
First, look into git log and find the point where I diverged, usually at a line like:
commit LAST_SHA_BEFORE_MY_BRANCH (upstream_branch_name, branch_name)

This may or may not be the target branch for PR, it could be branch of my previous PR. This happens often if there is some blocker in merging PRs. In those cases, I can end up with hierarchy like this:
TICKET-10-branch -> TICKET-07-branch -> TICKET-02-branch -> pr_target_branch

My steps then are
git reset --soft LAST_SHA_BEFORE_MY_BRANCH
git commit -m "Description message" -m "TICKET: #TICKET_NUM"
git fetch upstream_repo_remote pr_target_branch
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
git push -f

There are two unknowns that are not easy to automate (for me):

The point of divergence
What should the target branch be - even if there is some other PR branch in between. The branches are all rebased and merged in order, meaning rebase to pr_target_branch should not have any conflicts even if originally based on TICKET-XX branch

The first one could be matched by looking on the first line in git log that has something in round braces like (name, name2). But parsing got log with regex does not feel safe.
The second might not be possible to tell in general, but I could simply look into branch ancestry to find first branch that does not contain TICKET-XXX. But I don't even know how to get such a list.
Edit regarding merge-base:
I tried experimenting with it, and it is not helpful:

git merge-base --fork-point HEAD gives the SHA of the first commit that diverges from parent branch, but I want to do git reset to the commit I diverged FROM, not the first one I created.
git merge-base --fork-point parent_branch gives correct SHA, but I don't know the base branch name, so this is a Catch 22 problem


Can you not use git merge --squash?

No, merging is done only via github after some additional steps that cannot be automated. This is why there is also the need to chain branches like I described. I really need the automation of the steps the way I described above.

About the first point, you could use git merge-base to find the common ancestor commit between your feature branch and the one you're rebasing on top.

Yes, I was experimenting with that. While doing so, I accidentally reset to a completely different branch. But I am still investigating if it works in the cases described above. At least that would let me automate everything except what the correct rebase branch is.

"the correct branch" is probably something that is described in the PR itself (the target branch) rather than in raw git data. Since you talk about PR, you are probably using about a service such as github, azure devops, gitlab ... To access data stored in the PR part of these services, look at the API these services offer.

@LeGEC I might need to reword the question. The existence of a PR here is not required, this is just about making that if there IS a PR, the branch related to it satisfied the requirements I described. That is, the targed branch should be extracted from git history. In fact, it would be neat if Github also did that, since it does actually always default to wrong target branch when I create PRs.

Just remove the repo, check it out fresh, and it works
